# Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: --manifestdir

Tags: vagrant, puppet, matomo

I was trying to install [piwik-dev-environment](https://github.com/piwik/piwik-dev-environment). According to instructions I cloned the repo, installed Vagrant and executed `vagrant up`. The process ended with the following error:

```
Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: --manifestdir
```

Full logs are here:

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'trusty64' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
==> default: Box file was not detected as metadata. Adding it directly...
==> default: Adding box 'trusty64' (v0) for provider: virtualbox
    default: Downloading: https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/vagrant/trusty/current/trusty-server-cloudimg-amd64-vagrant-disk1.box
    default: Progress: 100% (Rate: 1170k/s, Estimated time remaining: --:--:--)
==> default: Successfully added box 'trusty64' (v0) for 'virtualbox'!
==> default: Importing base box 'trusty64'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: piwik-dev-environment_default_1438688840836_21904
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: private key
    default: Warning: Connection timeout. Retrying...
    default:
    default: Vagrant insecure key detected. Vagrant will automatically replace
    default: this with a newly generated keypair for better security.
    default:
    default: Inserting generated public key within guest...
    default: Removing insecure key from the guest if it's present...
    default: Key inserted! Disconnecting and reconnecting using new SSH key...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Setting hostname...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Mounting shared folders...
    default: /vagrant => D:/Git/piwik-dev-environment
    default: /etc/puppet/files => D:/Git/piwik-dev-environment/puppet/files
    default: /home/vagrant/www => D:/Git/piwik-dev-environment/www
    default: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/modules-48bf73244a40076992a5cef90c07f471 => D:/Git/piwik-dev-environment/puppet/modules
    default: /tmp/vagrant-puppet/manifests-768747907b90c39ab6f16fcb3320897a => D:/Git/piwik-dev-environment/puppet
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Reading package lists...
==> default: Building dependency tree...
==> default: Reading state information...
==> default: ruby is already the newest version.
==> default: 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
==> default: Successfully installed facter-2.4.4
==> default: Successfully installed json_pure-1.8.2
==> default: Successfully installed hiera-3.0.1
==> default: Successfully installed puppet-4.2.1
==> default: 4 gems installed
==> default: Installing ri documentation for facter-2.4.4...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for json_pure-1.8.2...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for hiera-3.0.1...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for puppet-4.2.1...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for facter-2.4.4...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for json_pure-1.8.2...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for hiera-3.0.1...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for puppet-4.2.1...
==> default: Successfully installed hiera-3.0.1
==> default: 1 gem installed
==> default: Installing ri documentation for hiera-3.0.1...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for hiera-3.0.1...
==> default: Successfully installed hiera-1.3.4
==> default: Successfully installed hiera-puppet-1.0.0
==> default: 2 gems installed
==> default: Installing ri documentation for hiera-1.3.4...
==> default: Installing ri documentation for hiera-puppet-1.0.0...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for hiera-1.3.4...
==> default: Installing RDoc documentation for hiera-puppet-1.0.0...
==> default: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> default: Running Puppet with site.pp...
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: --manifestdir
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

I tried to find a file that contains the `--manifestdir` option but I didn't find any. I also tried to apply the same patch as in https://github.com/joebew42/diaspora-replica/issues/10 but it didn't help.

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this was caused by a gem behavior.

I changed the SHELL provisioner to fetch and install the deb repo and installed the Puppet package for Ubuntu and I got past this issue.

```
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-SHELL
    if [ ! -f /deb-get ]; then wget https://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb  && sudo touch /deb-get; fi
    if [ ! -f /deb-run ]; then sudo dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-trusty.deb  && sudo touch /deb-run; fi
    if [ ! -f /apt-get-run ]; then sudo apt-get update && sudo touch /apt-get-run; fi
    if [ ! -f /apt-get-puppet ]; then sudo apt-get install --yes --force-yes puppet && sudo touch /apt-get-puppet; fi
  SHELL

  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "puppet"
    puppet.manifest_file  = "site.pp"
    puppet.module_path    = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.hiera_config_path = "hiera.yaml"
    puppet.options = "--verbose --debug"
    puppet.working_directory = "/tmp/vagrant-puppet"
    puppet.facter = [
        ['fdqn',  config.vm.hostname],
        ['db_username',  CONF['db_username']],
        ['db_password',  CONF['db_password']],
        ['ssh_username', CONF['ssh_username']],
    ]
  end
```

This left the following issues:

```
==> default: Warning: Could not retrieve fact fqdn
==> default: Error: Could not find class apt for piwik-trusty64 on node piwik-trusty64
==> default: Error: Could not find class apt for piwik-trusty64 on node piwik-trusty64
```

But those are issues that can be fairly easily fixed.

Comment: You can find the Vagrantfile in the repo: https://github.com/piwik/piwik-dev-environment/blob/master/Vagrantfile

Comment: `pupped.manifest_file` was already set to `"site.pp"` (https://github.com/piwik/piwik-dev-environment/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L62)

Comment: Updated answer to reflect how I got it to work on a clone of the repo.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you're trying to run the puppet provisioner with puppet4 installed on the guest machine. The --manifestsdir option is now deprecated  and will cause an error. You have to add several parameters to your Vagrantfile to tell Vagrant that you're using the 4th version of Puppet.

The solution to your problem is described here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/pull/5601

Comment: A more full solution/explanation is here: https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5615#issuecomment-150589920

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the Piwik dev-environment project isn't maintained and doesn't work (a lot of issues are open in the tracker).

I have opened a pull request to embedded the Vagrant configuration straigth into Piwik's repository (which hopefully would be simpler to use too). Please comment in the pull request if you find it useful: https://github.com/piwik/piwik/pull/8542