# Vagrant Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: --manifestdir

Tags: linux, vagrant, puppet

I am getting following error when i run `Vagrant up`, after google i found people saying puppet latest version doesn't support that option, but don't know how to fix that issue?

```
==> centos7base: Running provisioner: puppet...
==> centos7base: Running Puppet with site.pp...
==> centos7base: Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: --manifestdir
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Vagrant version: `1.7.4`

Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "puppet" do |puppet|
    puppet.facter = {
      "vagrant" => "1"
    }
    puppet.manifests_path = ["vm", "/Vagrant/puppet"]
    puppet.hiera_config_path = "puppet/hiera.yaml"
    puppet.module_path = "puppet/modules"
    puppet.manifest_file = "site.pp"
  end
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error: Could not parse application options: invalid option: --manifestdir](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31811458/error-could-not-parse-application-options-invalid-option-manifestdir)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using a folder in relation to the Vagrantfile's location, Vagrant is smart enough to mount it into the instance all by itself.

This is an example from a working instance for my development machine. Which has vagrant/Vagrantfile, but it also has folders for manifests and modules in the same vagrant/ folder as subdirectories.

```
  config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
    puppet.manifests_path = "manifests"
    puppet.module_path = "modules"
    puppet.options = ['--verbose']
    puppet.facter = {
        "fqdn" => "vagrant-test.domain.env"
    }
  end
```

Comment: later i found problem was puppet version `4.x` , I was using puppetlab-centos7 image which comes with puppet-4.2.1. I uninstall puppet 4.2.1 and install puppet-3.8.1 and it did work!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem using the Ubuntu / xenial64 box; the solution was
to install the `puppet-common` package. I provisioned through shell its installation as below:

config.vm.provision "shell", path: "install-puppet.sh"

File content install-puppet.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp
wget http://apt.puppetlabs.com/puppetlabs-release-pc1-xenial.deb
dpkg -i puppetlabs-release-pc1-xenial.deb
apt-get update
apt-get -y install puppet-common
echo "PATH=/opt/puppetlabs/bin:$PATH" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
echo "export PATH" >> /etc/bash.bashrc
export PATH=/opt/puppetlabs/bin:$PATH
```